# DataGridView throws SelectionChanged event for column 0 upon creation

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling

I have a base class that extends *DataGridView*:

```
public abstract class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
```

I then have a class that extends *MyDataGridView*. Here is the class definition and the constructor:

```
// ::FunctionGridView
public class FunctionGridView : MyDataGridView 
{
    private static int NUM_COLUMNS = 12;
    private static int NUM_ROWS = 1;

    public FunctionGridView()         
    {
        // call the method in the base class to setup the grid
        setupGridView(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLUMNS);
    }
}
```

The column type used for my data grid is *DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn*. Here is the code to setup the columns (defined in the base class):

```
// ::MyDataGridView
protected void setupGridView(int numRows, int numColumns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        column.Name = "Column" + (i + 1).ToString();
        this.Columns.Add(column);
    }
}
```

I want to catch the *SelectionChanged* event when the user clicks a cell and then toggle the checkbox for the selected cell. The callback is set in the base class constructor as follows:

```
// ::MyDataGridView
// initialize the controls then add the event handler
public MyDataGridView()
{            
    initialize();
    this.SelectionChanged += selectionChanged;
}
```

The selection changed callback is defined as follows:

```
// ::MyDataGridView
// get the checkbox _checked_ value and toggle it for the selected cell
private void handleSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentRow = this.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int currentColumn = this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    bool cellChecked = (bool)this.Rows[currentRow].Cells[currentColumn].Value;
    this.Rows[currentRow].Cells[currentColumn].Value = !cellChecked;
}
```

Everything works fine except there is one anomaly that I don't know how to handle..

When the program starts and the *DataGridView* is constructed and added to my *Panel* the *SelectionChanged* event is thrown initially for *Row[0].Cell[0]*. This event is being called even though the user never actually clicked on that cell.

The result is, when my program starts, the first cell gets checked without any user click. My data grid view ends up looking like the following:

[image: DataGridView Initial Cell Checked]

Do I need a way to determine if the *SelectionChanged* callback is being thrown during initialization and *not* from a user click then exit my callback without toggling the checkbox value?

```
// ::MyDataGridView
private void selectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    **// if (e.isInitializing()) return;**
    ....
    ....
}
```

I seem to recall in the Java *ActionEvent* class you can call *getSource* to make sure the event was triggered by the control and not some other source. Is there something equivalent in C#?

**==============================================================================**

*NOTE* to keep my question simple I used basic names and left out most of the detail. The real class/base class names are FunctionKeyTimer and KeyTimer (base class). If it helps, here is the class diagram and the full source code:

[image: Class Diagram]

```
public abstract class KeyTimer : DataGridView
{
    public static int WIDTH = 640;
    public static int HEIGHT = 40;

    private bool initialCheckedValue = false;

    public KeyTimer()
    {            
        initialize();
        this.SelectionChanged += selectionChanged;
    }

    public KeyTimer(bool initialChecked)
    {            
        this.initialCheckedValue = initialChecked;
        initialize();
        this.SelectionChanged += selectionChanged;
    }

    protected void setupGridView(int numRows, int numColumns, string columnNamePrefix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            column.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            column.Name = columnNamePrefix + (i + 1).ToString();
            this.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            this.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
            {
                row.Cells[i].Value = this.initialCheckedValue;
            }
        }
    }

    private void selectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentRow = this.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int currentColumn = this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        bool cellChecked = (bool)this.Rows[currentRow].Cells[currentColumn].Value;
        this.Rows[currentRow].Cells[currentColumn].Value = !cellChecked;
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        this.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        ....
        ....
    }
}

public class FunctionKeyTimer : KeyTimer
{
    private static int NUM_COLUMNS = 12;
    private static int NUM_ROWS = 1;
    private static string COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX = "F";

    public FunctionKeyTimer()         
    {
        setupGridView(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLUMNS, COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add your event handler AFTER you initialise your components.

Comment: I modified my original post to show the constructor where I setup the data grid and add the handler. As you can see, I add the _SelectionChanged_ callback **after** the initialization.

Comment: Are you using windows forms and using the Visual Studio Form Editor? If so, try setting the checkbox programatically, before you add the event handler. That will rule out if it is an issue with anything there.

Comment: Do you need to do something custom in the SelectionChanged method? If all you want to do is toggle the checkbox you don't need to do anything, you can remove the subscription to the SelectionChanged event and the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn will handle the toggling for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well I never had an issue with events like that when I used the form editor. The events wouldn't be called until the components were drawn.

I think it is because you are adding your event handler, before you programmaticly check the box. Hence it is getting triggered by your own code. Put some debug messages in to determine the order of operation. It might be as simple as moving some functions around.

Other than that, try printing out **sender.name** in your event listener to see if it changes between a user check and a programmatic check.

I hope that helps :)

~ Dan

Comment: Omg these kinds of things always happen at 3 in the morning when I have something due! :) I put a _Console.Writeline("Selection Change")_ statement in the _selectionChanged_ callback but for some strange reason I don't see the message "Selection Changed" in the VS Output (debug) window. What happend to my Console?? :( (I know the callback is being executed because when I put a breakpoint at the _Console.Writelin_ method it gets hit every time while debugging.

Comment: Did it ever work? can you +1 my answer? Try creating a new event handler. Check out the "onload" function in this code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens with the out of the box `DataGridView` also.

The standard fix is to attach your selection changed handler during the `DataBindingComplete` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use :

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
cb.Name = "The Name";
cb.HeaderText = "The Name";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cb);
row.Cells[2].Value = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value = true;
```